# How do I create a datatable column that uses the data from other columns?

Tags: javascript, datatables

For each column I've built I use data from the database. However, for the last column I need to sum up data from the database rather than bring it directly. Meaning, for each row, the last cell will be a calculation of other cells from different columns.

How can I do this? Everywhere I've searched I only managed to find how to make a last row that sums up everything on the column, but that's not what I want...

Comment: What have you tried? I've done something like this before but I'm curious as to what you've tried

Comment: Any code or query?

Comment: I've tried replacing it after the table is initialized but you can't do that apparently. And i've tried replacing during initializing the datatable with something I've scraped. Something like this.

"columnDefs": [
        { targets : [ 5 ], data:  function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
            return parseInt(row[4],10) + parseInt(row[3],10);
            }
         } 
      ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from what you're asking, I'd take a look at the `column.render` [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html). Just to give you an example of how I myself actually use it.

```
$('#display_table').dataTable({
    ...
    "columns" : [
        {data: 'col1' },
        {data: 'col2' },
        {data: 'sum_col', render: function(data, type, row) {
            return row[0] + row[1]
        } }, // Column to show the sum
    ]
});
```

The code above is just a rough sample of what you could do, but that should give you a good idea on how to access the row data for a custom `sum_col` that displays the sum for certain rows.

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot, dude! 
Do you have an idea of how to approach things if instead of row[0] or row[1] I want to bring some data from the database? Not something that's in the datatable?

Comment: Hmm, not sure how you're passing data to your datatable but you can pass rows with data that you're not going to display and just access it through the `render`'s row parameter. However on the note of not having to access it using `row[index]`, not sure if datatable would allow that through the `render` function. You could possibly use `drawCallback` and manually compute each row's **sum column**, but that would make things more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, than you have to use window functions. Here's postgres realization. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Please, make your answer more-less readable from SO directly. Links should only extend than answer